# subfigures in a custom float (subcaption & float packages)

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I need figures and subfigures with a custom caption name.
In order to achieve my goal I am trying to use `float` package to define new float type, and `subfigure` to create the subfigures.

However, I get compilation error messages. I reduced the code to this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{program}{thb}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{document}
\begin{program}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            A
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            B
    \end{subfigure}
\end{program}
\end{document}
```

where I get an error `Missing number, treated as zero` at the location where `subfigure` is used. In the produced output I get a weird `==0` at the beginning of each subfigure.

However, if I fall back to use stock `figure` instead of my custom replacement `program`, I get no errors and an expected output.

Where is it coming from and how can I avoid this? Should I use different packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use the `newfloat` and `subcaption` packages that are linked together with the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

% declare a new float type
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lop,
  listname={List of Programs},
  name=Program
]{program}
% announce the float to subcaption and create the subprogram environment
\DeclareCaptionSubType{program}

\begin{document}

\begin{program}
\centering
\begin{subprogram}{0.3\textwidth}
  A
\subcaption{A program}
\end{subprogram}
\begin{subprogram}{0.3\textwidth}
  B
\subcaption{Another one}
\end{subprogram}
\caption{Two programs}
\end{program}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason I get an error `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` already defined (using MiKTeX 2.9), but removing the `\usepackage{newfloat}` solved that issue and everything compiles.

Comment: @CygnusX1 The `newfloat` package is recent; its author removed some code from `caption` and from it he created the new package. You should update your TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg `\DeclareCaptionSubType{program}` is superfluous (but does not make any harm). `\DeclareCaptionSubType` is only needed if the new environment is not defined with `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`, e.g. with `\newfloat` offered by the `float` package instead.