# Switching from subfig to subcaption: Unknown float option `H'

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to switch my document from using the `float` and `subfig` packages to using `subcaption`. The thing is, I want to have `\begin{figure}[H]`, which I had before; but now I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.844 \begin{figure}[H]
```

What should I do? If I can't make this option available to me, can I achieve the same effect some other way (e.g. wrapping the float in a minipage? Something less ugly?)

Comment: the H option is defined by the float package, if you stop using that package, stop using H

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See edit...

Comment: you could just use a minipage (since H more or less just makes the figure a minipage and not a float) but can you not use the float package in conjunction with subcaption?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I try to, I get the dreaded ` LaTeX Error: Command \float@end already defined.` error.

Comment: as always, if you want help with an error post an example that makes it:-) (too late to look tonight but someone can)

Comment: perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118327/1090 (but don't vote for egreg:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the `float` package *is compatible* with `subcaption`. You just need to make sure and `\usepackage{float}` in the right place - namely, before `\usepackage{hyperref}` --- as [otherwise you get an error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93827/error-float-sty-line99).

When you do that, your `\begin{figure}[H]`'s will be positioned like they used to with no complaints.

Thanks @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: Even with `float` before `hyperref`, I get the error. The only solution for me was to remove `subcaption`.

Comment: Same experience here on the newest versions of texlive.  What have you replaced subcaption with @MartinMonperrus ?