# Weird float placement compilation error on some TeXLive installations

Tags: floats, positioning, texlive

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
Some text after the figure.
\end{document}
```

Until recently, this compiled fine on my Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster) system. Then after an `apt-get dist upgrade` a month and a half ago, it stopped compiling, complaining about the H placement:

```
 LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

However, on my laptop, with Ubuntu 18.04.3 (Bionic) - it continues to work.

Why could this be happening? And - how can I circumvent this?

Notes:

**Effect of source tweaking**

- If I remove the `\usepackage{subcaption}` - it works.
- If I move the `\usepackage{subcaption}` after the float - it still doesn't work.
- If I replace `[H]` with `[h]` - it works.

**TeXLive versions**

- New broken system: 2018.20190227-2
- Working laptop system:  2017.20180305-1

**Full log:**

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 18 June 2019, version: 4.65.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex --shell-escape  -recorder  "a.tex" -file-line-error -synctex=1'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (./a.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \begin{figure}[H]

?
```

Comment: you probably need to update the float package on the system where it doesn't work. (It works in a fully updated texlive 2018 and in texlive 2019)

Comment: It also works in Texlive shipped with Debian buster. Might it be that you haven't upgraded *all* texlive related packages during the upgrade?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I just did that, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are using a local (possibly changed) copy of `float.sty`. Try removing that. Well, you were, now you edited it out...

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: I `apt-get dist-upgrade`ed... is there anyway I could verify the "version integrity" of what I have?

Comment: @einpoklum You could post the file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty` somewhere so we can check against our versions...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Pastebin: [here](https://pastebin.com/JnWh3uGs). Box.com: [here](https://app.box.com/s/6fcy7ami8cdxk0pkayzusq7d37hf090o).

Comment: On Debian I usually do `apt list --installed | grep -v /stable` to show packages which belong to other branches than stable

Comment: @einpoklum Your version is identical to mine (up-to-date TL 19). Really weird...

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: https://pastebin.com/D1S7XzXe

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Not that weird... I suspect `float` has not been changed in quite a while.

Comment: @einpoklum Exactly. Weird that it raises an error...

Comment: the check on float types was added in 2015 (2015-01-11  David Carlisle  <latex-bugs@latex-project.org>`  if that helps you narrow down differences.

Comment: you have had this before... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380927/switching-from-subfig-to-subcaption-unknown-float-option-h

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That had a different cause though :-P  It looks like `\begin{figure}[H]` is like a mine canary for me.

Comment: @einpoklum The `float` package checks for an `H` immediatelly following the `[`. If it's not found, everything is passed to LaTeX's float mechanism which will behave as if there was no `float` package. It looks to me that `float` isn't seeing the `H` (for some reason), and then passing that `H` to LaTeX, which then complains. Really stupid, but try deleting the `\begin{figure}[H]` line and typing it again to make sure no weird character comes between `[` and `H`...

Comment: @einpoklum not really, I suspect. Once you trace what is happening here it will be the same as that, basically.

Comment: @einpoklum Could you post your version of `subcaption` (and `caption` and `caption3`) on pastebin too?

Comment: if you put `\tracingmacros1` as the first line of the test file above you should get a 3Mb log file which you could zip up and send to me (google my name for a gmail address) (oh or pastebin is OK)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: [Here you go](https://pastebin.com/4Pj5ukuQ).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: [Here you go](https://app.box.com/s/0ayl2ad6rc27knuimhb7tud8wu2khozu) (that's a compressed archive on  box.com with the `.log` and the `.tex` file). Also emailed it to you.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks. Could you please send `caption` and `caption3` as well? `subcaption` is just a thin wrapper around those and doesn't help much here. (Also, I think David meant the `.log` file with `H`, not `h`.)

Comment: first diff is texlive has 2019/09/01 v1.3a Sub-captions  but you have a 2018 one

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: The box.com archive now has all of float, caption, subcation and caption3, and the .log file with `H` and the failure rather than the success.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The box.com archive now has all of float, caption, subcation and caption3, and the .log file with H and the failure rather than the success. Same link.

Comment: ah I see you fixed it, I was confused as you sent me an error-free log, but I finally noticed that was the h case not H :-)

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr : Your distro packaged a bad version of `caption.sty`.

This is due to your machine using a particularly inopportune version of the Debian SID texlive-latex-recommended package. A [bug](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/64) in `caption.sty` resulted in this failure; while it was promptly fixed, the `texlive-latex-recommended` package picked up the buggy `caption.sty`.

If you download an up-to-date versions of the the [`subcaption` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption), and place it your local texmf tree - the document should compile fine.

Also - check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. There was a known glitch in some scenarios of upgrading to Devuan Beowulf which put APT lines for the Devuan Unstable repositories (ceres rather than beowulf) in the APT sources.

---

Thanks @DavidCarlisle for pointing me in that direction and @PhelypeOleinik for pinpointing the exact bug.

Comment: It was a bug in `caption.sty`. Your version had `\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\caption@ORI@xfloat{#1}[{#2}]\caption@settype{#1}}`, while the new has `\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\caption@ORI@xfloat{#1}[#2]\caption@settype{#1}}`. This made the `\@ifnextchar` test see the extra `{` instead of `H` when looking for it.

Comment: More on that: The bug was reported [here](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/64), and it apparently lasted one single day on CTAN. Your debian packaging chose the wrong day to update its version :-)

Comment: Installing the “vanilla TUG” TeX Live is a one-time-a-year burden. It allows you to update packages without waiting for Debian do it; and you'll have the last stable version of TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg: Is that what I get if I simply download TeXLive directly? Or is there some "annual TUG distro"?

Comment: @einpoklum TeX Live is released once a year. Packaged versions provided by GNU/Linux distributions may (and usually do) lag behind.